# time series forecasting using R CARET package

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, r-caret

I am new to the CARET package. I was wondering how it can be used to forecast multivariate time series data.

```
data(economics)
library(caret)
library(kernlab)

 myTimeControl <- trainControl(method = "timeslice", initialWindow =200,horizon =50, fixedWindow  = TRUE)

svmRbftune <- train(unemploy ~ pce + pop + psavert + uempmed,
                data = economics[1:250,], method = "svmRadial",
                tunelength = 14, trControl = myTimeControl)

svmpredict<-predict(svmRbftune,economics[251:350,])
```

But then how can we predict one step ahead from here

Comment: Wouldn't "one step ahead" mean predicting sample 251 via `svmpredict<-predict(svmRbftune,economics[251,])`?